# Finding algorithm: desire RSA's uniqueness and ECDSA's space efficiency

Tags: rsa, signature, dsa

I am asking for help in finding a signature algorithm with the following property:

1. Given a message `m` and a private key `prikey`, the result of signing `m` with `prikey` is unique (which is stricter than deterministic). In another word, there is only one signature (or finding another one using `prikey` is securely hard) that can pass the verification by the public key of `prikey`.
2. High space efficiency of storing private key and signature.

ECDSA's space efficiency is satisfying, but the signature is not unique; RSA has uniqueness, but is there any alternative with better space efficiency?

Comment: ECDSA signatures can be made to enjoy the uniqueness property you require. See http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/851/can-ecdsa-signatures-be-safely-made-deterministic

Comment: @BarackObama Deterministic is not unique.

Comment: I think [BLS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLS_(cryptography)) is (or can be made) unique. Its signatures have half the size of ECDSA signatures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes!  There are *verifiably pseudorandom functions* or VRFs made out of elliptic curves including [EC-VRF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-goldbe-vrf-01#section-5), related to ECDSA, and [VXEdDSA](https://signal.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/#vxeddsa), related to EdDSA.  In addition to getting a *unique* output for each message, the output is a *pseudorandom function* of the message, and you get a proof of uniqueness.

[More references on VRFs.](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50683)