# What is the difference between signatures and VRF?

Tags: signature, verifiability, verifiable-random-function

For example we have asymmetric signature scheme(RSA or ECC based) and VRF(also can be RSA/ECC based), both of them can be verified using public key of the signer/hasher and also are unique for each message. So what is the difference?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

First, you need more than just a signature, because a VRF produces both an *output* and a *proof*.  To an observer, the output is uniformly distributed unless the observer also has the proof, which can be used to verify the output.

With a signature scheme and a random oracle $H$, you could use a signature $s$ on a message $m$ as a proof and $h = H(s)$ as an output: then the output $h$ is uniformly distributed if you don't know the proof, but knowing the proof $s$ you can (a) verify that $s$ is a signature on $m$, and (b) verify that $h = H(s)$.

However, that's not enough, because signature schemes *do not* usually guarantee uniqueness of the signature.  [ECDSA signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_Curve_Digital_Signature_Algorithm) are malleable: if $(x(R), s)$ is an ECDSA signature, then so is $(x(-R), -s) = (x(R), -s)$.  [EdDSA signatures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EdDSA), of the form $(R, s)$ instead, hash $R$ together with the message so it can't be changed any more than the message can, but $(R, s + \ell)$ makes another valid signature if encodable, where $\ell$ is the order of the standard base point.

Further, ECDSA and EdDSA are built out of a non-interactive zero-knowledge proof protocol that is necessarily randomized, and the signer can choose any per-signature secret randomization they want without the verifier noticing.  Standard EdDSA prescribes a particular deterministic pseudorandomization so that the signer doesn't accidentally leak the private key when signing two different messages even if they don't have a source of entropy at signing time, but verifiers can't tell if a signer uses a nonstandard randomization.  Similarly, the widely deployed [RSASSA-PSS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8017#section-8.1) signature scheme is randomized, so it doesn't provide uniqueness either.

That said, we can still use the RSA primitive to make a VRF if we pick a *deterministic* RSA signature scheme such as RSA-FDH with a fixed full-domain hash.  This is what the IETF Internet-Draft [draft-goldbe-vrf](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/draft-goldbe-vrf/), currently under discussion at the [CFRG](https://irtf.org/cfrg), does for [RSA-FDH-VRF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-goldbe-vrf-01#section-5).

We can also adapt elliptic curve signatures such as EdDSA to make a VRF, with a little more work.  I won't go into the details, but draft-goldbe-vrf has one construction called [EC-VRF](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/draft-goldbe-vrf-01#section-5), and [Open Whisper Systems](https://whispersystems.org/) (creators of [Signal](https://signal.org/)) developed another called [VXEdDSA](https://whispersystems.org/docs/specifications/xeddsa/#vxeddsa).

Further reading:

- VRFs were first introduced to the literature in [Silvio Micali, Michael Rabin, and Salil Vadhan, ‘Verifiable Random Functions’, Proceedings of the IEEE 54th Annual Symposium on Foundations of Computer Science, 1999](https://people.csail.mit.edu/silvio/Selected%20Scientific%20Papers/Pseudo%20Randomness/Verifiable_Random_Functions.pdf).
- VRFs were recently presented to the IETF for standardization, by [Sharon Goldberg, Dimitrios Papadopoulos, and Jan Včelák, ‘draft-goldbe-vrf-01: Verifiable Random Functions (VRF)’, Presentation at CFRG@IETF'99, Prague, July 2017](http://www.cs.bu.edu/%7Egoldbe/papers/VRF_ietf99_print.pdf).
- Sharon Goldberg's group at Boston University has an [ongoing practical VRF project with some references](https://www.cs.bu.edu/%7Egoldbe/projects/vrf).
- Some details of the constructions, and an application to DNSSEC for verifiable negative responses thwarting zone enumeration, are analyzed in [Dimitrios Papadopoulos, Duane Wessels, Shumon Huque, Moni Naor, Jan Včelák, Leonid Rezyin, and Sharon Goldberg, ‘Making NSEC5 Practical for DNSSEC’, IACR Cryptology ePrint Archive: Report 2017/099](https://eprint.iacr.org/2017/099).
- A [dialogue in five parts](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/58281/49826) summarizing a use case of VRFs for DNSSEC to authenticate negative answers without enabling zone enumeration or risking forgery in the face of online nameserver compromise.

P.S.  Fun fact: RSA signatures aren't uniformly distributed even if you don't know the *public key*.  Since every signature will involve an integer below the modulus $n$, with enough signatures one can solve the [German tank problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem) to [deanonymize signers in practice](https://eprint.iacr.org/2014/728).  Of course, you could do rejection sampling to force them below $2^{\lfloor\lg n\rfloor}$.

Comment: Great explanation thank you.