# consequences of using fixed values with OAEP

Tags: rsa, oaep, pkcs1

With DSA / ECDSA using a fixed $k$ means the private key can be trivially easily calculated from two different signatures. To remedy this [RFC6979 Deterministic Usage of the Digital Signature Algorithm (DSA) and Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm (ECDSA)](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6979) was developed.

[OAEP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimal_asymmetric_encryption_padding) / [PSS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probabilistic_signature_scheme), as described in PKCS#1 v2.0+, used randomized values as well.

For PSS I guess it isn't a huge problem since the only randomized element is the salt and the salt has a variable length with 0 being a valid length.

For OAEP my assumption is that the only issue with a fixed `seed` is that if the same message were encrypted twice you'd be see the same ciphertext each time. Or is there another more severe issue that the randomized `seed` protects against?

I note that the original encryption described in PKCS1 employees randomized padding as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you encrypt something with low entropy but use a fixed seed for OAEP, it is trivial to brute force it, and verify your guesses with public key, while randomized all or nothing padding will make verifying a guess impossible.

In the context of signatures rather than encryption, it doesn't seem as severe, but you are supplying the attacker with a bunch of related plain text cipher text pairs which can't be a good idea.

Comment: This is not peculiar to OAEP—public-key encryption is _necessarily_ randomized to defeat a mere CPA or even KPA distinguisher.  (The same is not so for signatures: _e.g._, Ed25519 is a deterministic function of the signing key and message, and there are also [VRFs](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50683) which come with a verifiable proof of determinism.  RSA-PSS has a [funny history with randomization](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/67822); [more details](https://cr.yp.to/papers.html#rwtight).)