# How does the "biased-$k$ attack" on (EC)DSA work?

Tags: cryptanalysis, dsa

I recently stumbled across [Thomas Pornin's old answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/857/23623) about deterministic (EC)DSA again. There he states the following:

> Note that $k$ must be generated uniformly in the $[1, q-1]$ range
>   (where $q$ is the subgroup order). Any information on $k$, even
>   partial (such as: values between $1$ and $2^{160}-q$ are twice as
>   probable than values between $2^{160}-q$ and $q$), can be exploited by
>   the attacker.

When asked for clarification on this, [he responded](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/851/can-ecdsa-signatures-be-safely-made-deterministic#comment1428_857) with [a link to *"The Security of DSA and ECDSA Bypassing the Standard Elliptic Curve Certification Scheme"* by Vaudenay (PS)](http://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/99503/files/Vau03a.ps) which mentions that Bleichenbacher discovered the attack and mentioned it in private communication with the author.

Now the paper has a short paragraph (section 2.2), which basically states an approximate equation for the bias and says that

> Bleichenbacher actually used it in order to approximate the secret key more
>   and more precisely with signatures.

Now my question:
**How does this attack work in a more detailed description?** or formulated differently: How does one exploit this *tiny* bias to recover the secret key and how many signatures (ie oracle queries) are required for this along with what approximate computational effort (if it is non-negligible)?

---

The relevant section from the paper is (for your convenience):

> The initial standard pseudorandom generator in DSA for $k$ was simply
>   a 160-bit pseudorandom number reduced modulo $q$. Bleichenbacher
>   observed that the probability of $k$ in the $[0, 2^{160} − q]$ range
>   have probability which is twice of the others. This leads to a bias
>
> $$E\left(e^{\frac{2i\pi k}q}\right)\approx \frac{q
>  e^{i\pi\frac{N-1}q}}{\pi N} \times \sin\left(\frac{\pi N}q\right)$$
>
> where $N=2^{160}$. Since $q \approx N$, this may be large depending on
>   the $\frac{\pi N}q$ angle. Bleichenbacher actually used it in order to
>   approximate the secret key moreand more precisely with signatures.

Comment: If you also wonder how one could possibly arrive at the approximating equation, I have posted [an according question on Math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2182296/262906).

Comment: The attack is described with much more detail in two recent papers: [Mulder et al.](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/346) and [Aranha et al.](https://hal.inria.fr/hal-01094002/file/main.pdf).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Nguyen and Shparlinski detail the method in [The Insecurity of the Elliptic Curve Digital Signature Algorithm with Partially Known Nonces](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/0eb1/8a42b623dd8e7cdd4221085a6fd5503708ea.pdf). I'll largely follow the notation in that paper.

The idea is to convert the determination of a private key from biased $k$ nonces in several ECDSA signatures into instances of the [hidden number problem](http://crypto.stanford.edu/~dabo/abstracts/dhmsb.html) (HNP), and then solve the HNP as a reduction to the [closest vector problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lattice_problem#Closest_vector_problem_.28CVP.29).

So you collect a lot of signatures and construct a lattice out of them, and reduce that lattice using [LLL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenstra%E2%80%93Lenstra%E2%80%93Lov%C3%A1sz_lattice_basis_reduction_algorithm) or [BKZ](https://www.iacr.org/archive/asiacrypt2011/70730001/70730001.pdf), and then you can extract the private key from the reduced basis vectors.

---

### Estimated computational effort required

I tested this with a hand-crafted LLL Python implementation (it's so slow it surely must constitute an upper bound in performance...) running on a Ubuntu 16.04 VM with 2GB RAM, and I have the following sample runs:

- 96-bit bias, 5 signatures: (failed) 31 seconds
- 64-bit bias, 10 signatures: (success) 4 minutes
- 32-bit bias, 12 signatures: (success) 12 minutes
- 16-bit bias, 17 signatures: (success) 49 minutes
- 8-bit bias, 19 signatures: (failed) 79 minutes
- 8-bit bias, 21 signatures: (success) 244 minutes
- 8-bit bias, 20 signatures: (success) 177 minutes

I stopped there.  Nguyen and Shparlinski were apparently able to recover the secret key with only *3 bits of bias* with 100 signatures and think that recovery is possible with only 2 bits being known.

---

### More problem details and setup

So let's say you know the low $\ell$ bits of $k$. ([This paper](https://eprint.iacr.org/2013/346.pdf) describes one way of recovering those bits.) Then you can write $k$ as

$$k = a + 2^\ell b$$

In other words, you know $a \in [0, 2^\ell -1]$. For simplicity, let $a = 0$. Then the equation for $s$ in the ECDSA signature $(r,s)$ becomes

$$s = (h + rx) \cdot (2^\ell b)^{-1}$$

where $h$ is your hashed message and $x$ is your private key, and everything is modulo $q$, the order of your base point. Rewrite this as

$$xr \cdot (2^\ell s)^{-1} = -h \cdot (2^\ell s)^{-1} + b$$

Define $t \equiv r\cdot (2^\ell s)^{-1}$ and $u \equiv -h \cdot (2^\ell s)^{-1}$ and you have

$$xt = u + b$$

Remembering that $0 \lt b \lt q/2^\ell$, you have

$$xt - u \lt q/2^\ell$$

So this is basically the HNP. $b$ is smaller by a factor $1/2^\ell$ than $x$,$t$, and $u$, so approximate this equation:

$$xt - u \approx 0 \longrightarrow xt - u - jq \approx 0$$

since everything is mod $q$. So first collect $n$ signatures, giving you several tuples of $t_i$, $u_i$, and $j_i$, and you can construct a matrix out of basis vectors:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
q & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
0 & q & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & q \\
t_0 & t_1 & t_2 & \cdots & t_n \\
u_0 & u_1 & u_2 & \cdots & u_n \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

(The first $n$ rows contain all zeroes and one $q$, one for each of the unknown $j_i$.) This is an $(n+2) \times n$ matrix. Now let $T \equiv (t_0, t_1, \cdots, t_n)$ and $U \equiv (u_0, u_1, \cdots, u_n)$. Then the **short vector of interest, $X$** is going to be something like

$$U - xT + \text{(other stuff)}$$

You can modify your matrix to include "sentinel values" $s_T$ and $s_U$ so that you can identify $X$; if you see a reduced vector $T'$ with $s_T$ as its last slot, most likely you'll see the next-to-last entry containing $-x\cdot s_U$ from which you can recover $x$. Disclaimer: I saw this trick in a [cryptopals](https://cryptopals.com/sets/8) problem first and makes things way easier than just guessing. The modified matrix looks like:

$$ \begin{pmatrix}
q & 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & q & 0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots  & \vdots  & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & q & 0 & 0\\
t_0 & t_1 & t_2 & \cdots & t_n & s_T & 0 \\
u_0 & u_1 & u_2 & \cdots & u_n & 0 & s_U\\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Now you can use an implementation of LLL from [NTL](http://www.shoup.net/ntl/) or [fplll](https://github.com/fplll/fplll), find the sentinel value, and extract $x$.