# Can private key used in ECDSA be discovered when many signatures were colleced?

Tags: keys, dsa

Can private key used in ECDSA be discovered when many signatures of different messages were collected (1M+) or may signatures of the same message were collected?

Will small nonce bias be easily exploitable?

Comment: The bias [How does the “biased-k attack” on (EC)DSA work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44644/18298)

Comment: Thanks for the link.