# Short Nonces in ECDSA signature generation

Tags: elliptic-curves, dsa, attack, nonce

Recently I noticed that my device generates *short-sized* `Nonces`.

Approximately $2 ^ {243} - 2^{244}$.

Could it turn out that there will be a small leak of information about the first ***3 bits*** of `Nonces`?

Accordingly, if `Nonces` is short, then it must contain null at the beginning.
That is, the first ***3 bits*** of `Nonces` contain null at the beginning.

*Hence, for the sake of safety:*

When creating an **ECDSA** signature, the value of *signatures* $[R, S, H (e)]$ that in this `Nonces` signature is short in size can be disclosed to an attacker?

Comment: [How does the "biased-k attack" on (EC)DSA work?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/44644/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka Please show me an example of how with  signatures `[R, S, H (e)]` can tell that `Nonces` is  short-sized?

Comment: https://eprint.iacr.org/2019/023.pdf

Comment: @kelalaka On which page is this information written?

Comment: Look at the second page.