# Help breaking ECDSA with biased nonces

Tags: elliptic-curves, nonce

I am currently trying to do the [cryptopals challenge 62](https://cryptopals.com/sets/8), breaking ECDSA with biased nonces, with the help of those two links ([1](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44644/how-does-the-biased-k-attack-on-ecdsa-work) [2](https://toadstyle.org/cryptopals/62.txt)) that describe accurately the attack. However, after around 15 hours, I still can't have it working, and I have absolutely no clue where I made a mistake.

Here is how I did it (using Python 3.6):
First, to generate the signatures with faulty nonces (I took the same model as the one those links use, so the 8 LSB bits are zero):

```
import ecdsa
from random import randint

gen = ecdsa.SECP256k1.generator
order = gen.order()
d = randint(1, order)

pub = ecdsa.ecdsa.Public_key(gen, gen*d)
priv = ecdsa.ecdsa.Private_key(pub, d)

R = []
S = []

for i in range(100):
    nonce = randint(1, order)
    nonce ^= (nonce & 0xff)
    signed = priv.sign(h, nonce)
    R.append(signed.r)
    S.append(signed.s)
```

then the actual attack, which is quite short: we compute a few numbers, construct a matrix with them, call the LLL algorithm and we should find in the reduced basis the value `-d*ct` right next to a `cu` one, according to the links:

Constructing the matrix:

```
h = 1337
N_SIGNATURE = 100

M = [[0 for i in range(N_SIGNATURE + 2)] for j in range(N_SIGNATURE + 2)]

for i in range(N_SIGNATURE):
    M[i][i] = order

ct = gmpy2.invert(256, order) # 2**l with l = known bits
cu = order * ct
M[-2][-2] = int(ct)
M[-1][-1] = int(cu)

for i in range(N_SIGNATURE):
    M[-2][i] = int(R[i] * gmpy2.invert(S[i] * 256, order)) % order    # t_i
    M[-1][i] = int( -h  * gmpy2.invert(S[i] * 256, order)) % order    # u_i
```

Using the very efficient [fplll](https://github.com/fplll/fplll) lib (this part is a bit clunky and will be rewritten using Sage, but it works. Here, I mainly do formatting on the matrix so it can be inputted for fplll, and I convert the output back to a matrix):

```
str_M = str(M).replace(",", "")
os.system("echo " + str_M + " | fplll -a lll -m proved -f mpfr > result.txt")

new_matrix = [[0 for i in range(N_SIGNATURE+2)] for j in range(N_SIGNATURE+2)]

with open("result.txt", "r") as myfile:
    contents = myfile.read()
    contents = contents.replace("[", "").replace("]", "").replace("\n", "").split(" ")
    contents = contents[:-1] # there is one empty line at the end

    assert(len(contents) == pow(N_SIGNATURE + 2, 2))

    i = 0
    j = 0
    for v in contents:
        new_matrix[i][j] = int(v)
        j += 1
        if j == N_SIGNATURE + 2:
            j = 0
            i += 1
```

Getting d:

```
for row in new_matrix:
    if(row[-1] == cu):
        d2 = (-row[-2] * gmpy2.invert(ct, order)) % order
        
        if(d2 == d):
            print("Secret key recovered")
```

However, no matter how many variables I adjust and things I try, I can't get a result. I also tried scanning the whole matrix instead of the last elements, without success. Did I make a silly mistake I didn't notice, or is there something quite wrong in my code?

Note: the following line in link 2:

> I forgot to mention: you'll want to write your implementation to work on vectors of rationals. If you have infinite-precision floats, those'll work too.

caught my attention, but the `mpfr` argument of fplll should fit what is needed here. And in case it doesn't, I also tried using a Sage matrix defined over QQ, but it doesn't work better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to be a bit careful of several things:

1. the fractional number $\frac{1}{2^l}$ is not the inverse of 2^l mod order.
2. after lattice reduction, the entries of the basis matrix might be negative values, so the statement if(row[-1] == cu) might not be fully correct.
3. note that order - d is also a solution of the HNP inequalities, so it might be safe to check both. Usually, lattice reduction will lead to the smaller one of d and order - d.
4. the vector you want might not be the first vector of the reduced basis, so you can check all the rows.

For 256-bit ECDSA with 8-bit leakage, I guess 50 (even 40) is enough.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Just fixing your point 1 made everything work right away. I never would have guessed a regular fraction was needed here, since everything is modulo the order and divisions are computed with the modular inverse.