# If I have two ECDSA signatures that use the same k (nonce) but different secret keys, can the secret key be computed?

Tags: signature, dsa

I have two ECDSA signatures $(r, s_1, z_1)$ and $(r, s_2, z_2)$
where $s_1 = (z_1 + r*x_1) / k$, and $s_2 = (z_2 + r*x_2) / k$.

Can $x_1$ & $x_2$ be computed?

Comment: Seem duplicate of this question; [Is it safe to reuse a ECDSA nonce for two signatures if the public keys are different?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/71764/18298)

Comment: @kelalaka It seems that this is a request to indicate how the *assumption* in the last sentence of that question can be computed. Slendep 1922 seems to have asked the same question in an answer to that question first. He converted it into a question when it was shown to him that you should not put questions in the answer field. That said, I've got a feel that answering this question will also solve the other one.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've come to this [rfc6979](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6979) written by Thomas and he gave an answer to a similar question [Can ECDSA signatures be safely made “deterministic”?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/851/18298), years ago

Comment: And I'd close this question down for that reason, but it doesn't seem to directly  answer the rather mathematical questions why the deterministic ECDSA is secure.